# I want my nx monorep to allow css and sass styling?

Tags: webpack, monorepo, nrwl-nx, micro-frontend, nrwl

I created an nx workspace and added CSS for styling but my project also uses SCSS files. How can I tell my nx workspace to accept SCSS files? Is there a command I can run?

Answer (score 1):

Do you try adding scss-loader and style-loader ?
For scss - https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/
css - https://webpack.js.org/loaders/style-loader/

try with this.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please [edit] the answer with all relevant information. Make sure to use your own words, [answers comprised entirely of a quote (sourced or not) will often be deleted since they do not contain any original content](/help/referencing).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).